# How to check if vue3 component prop is explicitly passed?

Tags: components, vuejs3

I am trying to pass a function as property inside a component in Vue3. Here is the code:

```
// ExampleComponent.vue

<template>
    Here goes component content...
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: ''
}
</script>

<script setup>
import { onMounted } from "vue"

const props = defineProps({
    onLoad: {
        type: Function,
        default() {
            return {}
        }
    }
})

onMounted(() => {
    if (props.onLoad) { // This doesn't work and passes every time
        props.onLoad()
    }
})
</script>
```

Here is the parent component calling child ExampleComponent.vue. It may or may not pass the onLoad function.

```
<ExampleComponent \>
```

What I want is that call this function only if the property on-load is passed? Is there a way in Vue3 to check if the property is passed explicitly?

Answer (score -1):

you can use watcheffect :

javascript

```
watchEffect(() => {
  if(props.onLoad) props.onLoad()
});
```

once '''onLoad''' value changed, it will tigger.